# Unable to disable autocomplete function

Tags: html, autocomplete

I am dead trying various combinations to stop browser (not only Chrome, but also Mozilla) from irritating autocomplete, and still no success. What I have for now:

```
<form id = 'user_form' autocomplete="off" role="form">
     <input name="hidden" type="text" style="display:none;">
     <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm" id="id_username" 
                   maxlength="30" name="username" 
                   placeholder="Имя пользователя" required="" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I did not post any JSFiddle, because it's no help for this question. I've also tried `false` in place of `off`. But no success again.

**UPDATE**

After following 's suggestion, I have modified the code to include hidden password input, and in Firefox it's all right now. But in Chrome autocomplete still works for real password-type inputs.

My code as is:

```
<form id = 'user_form' autocomplete="off" role="form">
   <input style="display:none"/>
   <input type="password" style="display:none"/>
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
         <div class = 'zeon_non_field_error_wrap'>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
         <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm" id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" placeholder="Имя пользователя" required="" type="text" />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
         <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm" id="id_password" maxlength="128" name="password" placeholder="Пароль" required="" type="password" />
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: So your question is: How can you disable 'autocomplete'?

Comment: Yes. Exactly...

Comment: --> Headline changed.

Comment: Is your issue only on Mozilla? Were you able to turn it off on chrome?

Comment: The issue persists both in Mozilla and Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that Chrome only autocompletes the first `<input type="password">` and the previous `<input>`.  So the workaround would be to add to the top of the `<form>`:

```
<input style="display:none">
<input type="password" style="display:none">
```

Depending on chrome versions. Works for me on Chrome 47

Comment: Well, can't you see the hidden input in my question? It doesn't help :(

Comment: Modified answer. You should add another hidden password field before your actual input field.

Comment: Text field is now without autocomplete. But I also have a password input, for which the issue still persists (autofill is on for it)

Comment: A new field not in your code? Can you modify your code so I can check it out?

Comment: I would like to emphasize that the problem with real password persists ONLY for Chrome. It's ok in Firefox

Comment: Sorry I'm not at computer to test it. First try adding type = "text" to your first hidden field. Let's see what happens.